# File extension counter app program ANDROID

Tags: java, android

I was able to make a program to get all the files from my phone's memory and display them in a text field.

What I am trying to do now is strip off all the file names and count the number of like file extensions.  I tried using map but my program just crashes.  Please help!  I believe that this is coming from a null value inside my string, I tried using the debug in eclipse to see why this was not putting the correct value into the map field but can't see to figure it out.

Thanks

Here is my code:

```
package com.sdfiletypes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Files;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int myNumber = 0;

String myString;
private TextView myFileTypes;
    //This is where I put the location of the directory I want it to find
    //I would like this to be recursive but not sure how to change it at this point
File myFile = new File("/storage/extSdCard/my_pix");
File[] pictures = myFile.listFiles();
String[] stringArray;
String[] newArray;
Map<String, Integer> myMap;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myFileTypes = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textFileType);

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();     

    stringArray = new String[pictures.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++)
    {
        stringArray[i] = pictures[i].getName().split("\\.")[1];

        if(myMap.containsKey(stringArray[i]))
        {
            myMap.put(stringArray[i], +1);

        }
        else
            myMap.put(stringArray[i], 1);
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: myMap.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();

        myFileTypes.append(key + " = " + value.toString() + "\n");
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using a List vice a Map using the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String myString;
private TextView myFileTypes;
File myFile = new File("/storage/extSdCard/my_pix");
File[] pictures = myFile.listFiles();
String[] stringArray;
boolean flag = false;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myFileTypes = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textFileType);

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    stringArray = new String[pictures.length];
    List<NameValuePair> myValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    for (int i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) {
        stringArray[i] = pictures[i].getName().split("\\.")[1];
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < myValuePair.size(); j++) {
            if (myValuePair.get(j).getName().equals(stringArray[i])) {
                int addOne = Integer
                        .parseInt(myValuePair.get(j).getValue()) + 1;
                myValuePair.set(j, new BasicNameValuePair(stringArray[i],
                        String.valueOf(addOne)));
                break;
            }
        }

        if (j == myValuePair.size()) {
            myValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(stringArray[i], String
                    .valueOf(1)));

        }

    }

    for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : myValuePair) {

        myFileTypes.append(nameValuePair.getName() + " - "
                + nameValuePair.getValue()) + "\n";
    }

}

}
```